# Remove created file after x minutes

Tags: files, at

I have a directory `/my/path/tmpimages`. Whenever a file is copied/created there, add a timer that remove that file after x minutes. What I found is that I need to use  **inoticoming** or **incrond** to watch for file create event on that directory and then add a timer on that file using **at**. I understood how to use at `echo "rm file" | at now + 30 minutes` but I couldnt find how to use inoticoming or incrond.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just scan the directory with a cron job entry using the find command.  Then delete a file that is older than X minutes.  I wouldn't think that having a periodic run of maybe every 15 minutes would be any sort of strain on the system and it would run all the time.

Comment: Imagine a file created and after few seconds the cron run. That mean that the file will be there for 45 minutes.

Comment: Hmmm...the max for a 15 minute cycle time would be 30 minutes.  You could run it once every minute .... thus the maximum window would be 2 minutes.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you but if there is a perfect solution why to not use it? :) Anyway if no one answer I will stick with what I did (exactly what you suggested)